# Attack + (to / on) (someone / something)

Tags: grammar, prepositions, verbs

I was wondering which preposition works with the verb "*[attack](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/attack)*"?

1.a- Army forces have been attacking the town since dawn. 
1.b- Army forces have been attacking **to** the town since dawn. 
1.c- Army forces have been attacking **on** the town since dawn.

2.a- I condemn that country for its attacks **to** civilians. 
2.b- I condemn that country for its attacks **on** civilians.

Personally, I think technically we can use it in the following way:

- **Attack somewhere** (without any preposition)
- **Attack *on* someone** (without any preposition) 
  Also I think an animal attacks another animal, without any preposition.
  Accordingly, in my view, the correct choices would be #1.a. and #2.b.
  I was wondering if I am right? If not, please do me a favor and clarify that to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your first set of examples, “attacks” is a transitive verb with direct object “the town”, so “attacks the town” is correct.

In your second set, “attacks” is a noun, so a preposition is required to provide *any* further detail. “on” is the correct one to specify the target.